# Based on crash in a program while running

Tags: c, crash

In the below program, when the user enter the input as 720 the program crashes. Why?

```
main()
{   
  for (;;) 
  { 
    int depth,i,j; 
    printf("enter the depth");  
    scanf("\n%d",&depth);   
    printf("first");    
    int arr[depth][depth];//at this line the program get crashed //
    printf("first1"); 
    for(i=0;i<depth;i++)    
    {
      for(j=0;j<=i;j++)         
      {         
        arr[i][j]=i+1;      
      }
    }       
    for(i=0;i<depth;i++)    
    { 
        printf("\n");       
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++)       
        {           
          printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);         
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: that's not how C works. you can't dynamically create an array like that. `depth` is UNDEFINED at the time of compile, and it's that undefined value that will be used to allocate space for `arr`. You need to prompt for the sizes, then `malloc()` some space at runtime.

Comment: Probably because of a stackoverflow.

Comment: @MarcB Isn't this VLA or am I missing something?

Comment: VLA? There's too many TLAs... (three-letter acronyms).

Comment: @MarcB: These dynamically allocated arrays are supported since C99, AFAIK (though `depth` really should be initialized to 0). He already prompts for the size, but I guess the size is too big for the stack (where the array is allocated).

Comment: the final loops are also doing `<=`, which means going 0->n, for a total of n+1 iterations.

Answer (score -1):

An array like that is allocated on the stack. If the user enters 720, you get an array with a size of `720*720*sizeof(int)` bytes. On a system with 32-bit `int`, that's almost 2MB. And you likely get exactly what this site is named after: a stack overflow!

Instead, allocate on the heap:

```
int **arr = malloc(depth * depth * sizeof(int));
```

You need to release the memory with `free(arr);` later on.